# Symfony - using orWhere() in doctrine query builder

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I want to return query result for the words I am searching in a message but just where userOne or userTwo is currently logged in user.

I think I have trouble with defining my query builder right because when testing otherwise logged in user is returned correctly.

I am trying with **orWhere()** clause but it always returns all results of that word not just for logged in user.

My code:

```
 public function search($word, $user)
{
    return $this->getMessageRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->where('a.message LIKE :message')
        ->andWhere("a.toUser = $user OR fromUser = $user")
        ->setParameter('message', '%' . $word. '%')
        ->setParameter('toUser', $user)
        ->setParameter('fromUser', $user)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic of the `where` statement should work as expected.
But it seems like you are using incorrect `parameter binding`.

`toUser` and `fromUser` are columns and therefore no need to bind them.

`$user` is the `target user` that we want to filter on, thus it should be bound to the query.

An example:

```
{
    return $this->getMessageRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->where('a.message LIKE :message')
        ->andWhere("a.toUser = :user OR a.fromUser = :user")
        ->setParameter('message', '%' . $word. '%')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you. @xtothea

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify all fields with a prefix `a` because you create this prefix in `createQueryBuilder('a')`;

If you have more 1 params use `setParameters`.

And you can OR write in QueryBuilder type -> `$builder->expr()->orX`.

Your query example:

```
public function search($word, $user)
    {
        $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
    
        return $builder
            ->where('a.message LIKE :message')
            ->andWhere($builder->expr()->orX(
                $builder->expr()->eq('a.toUser', ':user'),
                $builder->expr()->eq('a.fromUser', ':user'),
            ))
            ->setParameters([
                'message' => '%' . $word . '%',
                'user' => $user,
            ])
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```